# Save xml files separately with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Good evening, I already know how to write xml files in the same file, the matter now is how I write files now separately, example: file 1, file 2, file 3 ... Can someone tell me how to please ... For each xml write do one xml separately.

Currently I write the files like this and it works well, but I need to make xml file separately

```
                        Dim configuracionArchivo As New XmlWriterSettings

                    configuracionArchivo.Indent = True



                    Using escribiendoFactura As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("Facturas.xml", configuracionArchivo)
                        With escribiendoFactura


                            'Write the xml declaration
                            .WriteStartDocument()


                            .WriteStartElement("Facturas")

                            .WriteStartElement("Factura")


                            '.WriteStartElement("FechaCompra")
                            '.WriteString(lblFecha.Text)
                            '.WriteEndElement()

                            'Nodos de factura
                            .WriteStartElement("CedulaJuridica")
                            .WriteString(txtCedulaJuridica.Text.ToString)
                            .WriteEndElement()

                            



                            .WriteEndElement()

                            .WriteEndDocument()

                            .Flush()
                            .Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make a class level variable FileNumber. Then increment it on each call to the Sub. Simply tack the FileNumber on to the file name.

Do not call .ToString on a .Text property; it is already a string.

It shouldn't be necessary to call .Close when you have a Using block.

```
Private FileNumber As Integer

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim configuracionArchivo As New XmlWriterSettings
    configuracionArchivo.Indent = True
    Using escribiendoFactura As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create($"Facturas{FileNumber}.xml", configuracionArchivo)
        With escribiendoFactura
            'Write the xml declaration
            .WriteStartDocument()
            .WriteStartElement("Facturas")
            .WriteStartElement("Factura")
            '.WriteStartElement("FechaCompra")
            '.WriteString(lblFecha.Text)
            '.WriteEndElement()
            'Nodos de factura
            .WriteStartElement("CedulaJuridica")
            .WriteString(txtCedulaJuridica.Text)
            .WriteEndElement()
            .WriteEndElement()
            .WriteEndDocument()
            .Flush()
        End With
    End Using
    FileNumber += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, it does not continue after 1, it stays at 1

Comment: The first time you call the method, it should be zero. Next time one and so on. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Excuse me, I solved it with what I am above, thank you very much, I am making a form ... of company invoices

Comment: Can you explain why this is used $ "Invoices {FileNumber} .xml"
please

Comment: That is an interpolated string. You can insert variables exactly where you would like them to appear surrounding the variable in braces. They are available in Visual Studio 2015 and later. Previously you would use `String.Format`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the bit that says:

```
XmlWriter.Create("Facturas.xml", ...
```

So it says something else for the filename, like "facturas2.xml"..

Comment: it has to be at run time to change

Comment: I don't understand; your programming knowledge extends far enough that you know how to create an XML file that includes varying content from things like the `txtCedulaJuridica` variable's `.Text` property, but then you seem to be claiming that you don't know how to put a string into a variable and use it to change a filename? It's the same thing! There is no difference between `WriteString(txtCedulaJuridica.Text.ToString)` and `Create("Facturas.xml"...` - one is  method that takes a variable string, one is a method that takes a fixed string, and *you wrote them both*... Very confusing